# Alert notifications to user as file is processed in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails application that has file uploading. Once the file is uploaded I do a lot of processing on it. I'd like to send notifications to the user of the status of the processing. Would flash be best used for this? Thanks!

Comment: Let me know if this is what you are looking for: http://aquantum-demo.appspot.com/file-upload

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to notify the user of progress after the file has been uploaded, you'll want to:

- Kick off a background job on completion of the upload
- During the background job, update a table with the completion percentage
- Have your processing HTML page use ajax to poll the server for the completion percentage of the job
- Once completion percentage reaches complete, redirect to the page that displays your results